# Употребление двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли перед двоеточием поставить слово "это", если далее идет перечисление?

Основные тенденции на рынке ГРП — это:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это тема - тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. В Вашем предложении "это" является частицей, а не местоимением, значит, не может быть обобщающим словом, поэтому двоеточие не надо ставить.

Comment: Значит можно его просто убрать и тогда перечисление пойдет без всяких вводных слов?

Comment: Если Вы о слове "это", то его можно убрать, а можно и оставить. В любом случае надо ставить тире. А вводных слов здесь нет.

Answer (score 1):

"Это" является словом-связкой  между подлежащим и именным сказуемым при отсутствии глагольной связки, двоеточие после "это" не ставится.

Связка обычно используется в тех случаях, когда она помогает понять структуру предложения.